# Dark Theme Update Caused Stopage of Eclipse Launching

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, color-scheme

A DevStyle Update stopped Eclispe launching.

Last week, on Friday, eclipse automatically started and completed the devStyle update.

After update completion, I turned off pc.

Now after trying to open the eclipse, its failing again and again by showing following log

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: url
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeImages(Workbench.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Also I have figured out that `com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.evergreen.prefs` file also changed last week, after update. Its content is as below

```
devstyle.manifest.check.timestamp=1560491145538
eclipse.preferences.version=1
manifest.check.timestamp=1540825141573
manifest.devstyle.download.cache={"updates"\:{"release-version"\:"1.11.0.201906121516","eclipse-version"\:"[4.5.0,5.0.0)","release-notes"\:{"id"\:"ci20190313","delivery-log-url"\:"https\:\\/\\/www.genuitec.com\\/products\\/devstyle\\/deliverylog\\/","release-label"\:"CI 2019.3.13","updates"\:[{"heading"\:"DevStyle and Mojave Dark","message"\:"If you are running on macOS with Mojave, you now will automatically get dark window trim and menus\! Lots of other Mac fixes have gone in to clean up the theme consistency as well.","bullet"\:{"padding"\:"tiny","overlayicon"\:"ionicons\:ios-moon","color"\:"blue","overlayscale"\:"xlarge","icon"\:"fontawesome\:square","scale"\:"full","type"\:"overlayed","overlaycolor"\:"black","size"\:"32x32","position"\:"center"},"show-if"\:{"bundles"\:["com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.ui"]}},{"heading"\:"Theming Improvements","message"\:"Want to use regular Eclipse icons? DevStyle now supports it\! That and lots of other requests reported by our users have been addressed from HiDPI Trees on 4.10+ to improved Text box colors, and fixes for 2018-12 and 2019-03.","bullet"\:{"padding"\:"tiny","overlayicon"\:"ionicons\:ios-moon","color"\:"blue","overlayscale"\:"xlarge","icon"\:"fontawesome\:square","scale"\:"full","type"\:"overlayed","overlaycolor"\:"black","size"\:"32x32","position"\:"center"},"show-if"\:{"bundles"\:["com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.ui"]}}]},"eclipse-roots"\:[{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201906121516"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.designer.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201906121516"}],"binary-roots"\:[],"repository-url"\:"http\:\\/\\/downloads.genuitec.com\\/downloads\\/products\\/devstyle\\/updates\\/ds20190612","check-interval"\:28800000,"notify-updated"\:14400000},"notifications"\:[],"notifications2"\:[]}
manifest.devstyle.download.etag="5d013cc0-6c5"
manifest.devstyle.download.modified.date=Wed, 12 Jun 2019 17\:56\:16 GMT
manifest.devstyle.download.url=http\://www.genuitec.com/updates/devstyle/ci/devstyle.json
manifest.download.etag="5bd0b0ab-fb5"
manifest.download.modified-date=Wed, 24 Oct 2018 17\:49\:31 GMT
manifest.download.url=http\://www.genuitec.com/updates/webclipse/ci/webclipse.json
manifest.webclipse.download.cache={"updates"\:{"release-version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404","eclipse-version"\:"[4.5.0,5.0.0)","release-notes"\:{"id"\:"2017ci14","delivery-log-url"\:"https\:\\/\\/www.genuitec.com\\/products\\/webclipse\\/deliverylog\\/","release-label"\:"2017 CI 14","updates"\:[{"heading"\:"Deep Black Improved\!","message"\:"Our new Deep Black theme gets even better. Thanks for all the great suggestions\!","bullet"\:{"padding"\:"tiny","overlayicon"\:"ionicons\:ios-moon","color"\:"blue","overlayscale"\:"xlarge","icon"\:"fontawesome\:square","scale"\:"full","type"\:"overlayed","overlaycolor"\:"black","size"\:"32x32","position"\:"center"},"show-if"\:{"bundles"\:["com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.ui"]}},{"heading"\:"Ready for CodeMix 2?","message"\:"The next generation of Webclipse is coming in the form of CodeMix 2\! Be on the lookout for exciting updates.","bullet"\:{"size"\:"32x32","color"\:"orange","icon"\:"materialdesign\:update"},"show-if"\:{"bundles"\:["com.genuitec.eclipse.typescript","com.genuitec.eclipse.modernweb.angular2.ui"]}}]},"eclipse-roots"\:[{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.commons.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.angularide.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.jsdebugger.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.jsjet.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.angular2.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.10.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.navigation.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.explorer.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.minimap.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.rest.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.slack.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.terminal.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.livepreview.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.emmet.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241355"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.designer.feature.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241355"},{"id"\:"com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.suite.feature.group","version"\:"1.11.0.201810241404"}],"binary-roots"\:[],"repository-url"\:"http\:\\/\\/downloads.genuitec.com\\/downloads\\/products\\/webclipse\\/updates\\/wc2017ci14b","check-interval"\:28800000,"notify-updated"\:14400000},"notifications"\:[],"notifications2"\:[{"id"\:"lune-depracation-2","from"\:"2017-06-15","to"\:"2020-06-10","eclipse-version"\:"(0.0.0,4.5.0)","title"\:"Webclipse on Luna\!","message"\:"We're happy that you are enjoying using Webclipse on Luna and will continue to be able to do so. That said, Eclipse 4.4 aka Luna is not getting any more updates for Webclipse\! There are great new versions like Eclipse 4.6 Neon that you should consider upgrading to\! Upgrade now to stay up on the latest benefits of Webclipse.","action"\:{"label"\:"Upgrade Eclipse","url"\:"https\:\\/\\/www.eclipse.org\\/downloads\\/eclipse-packages\\/"}},{"id"\:"mars-java17-warning","from"\:"2017-06-15","to"\:"2020-06-10","eclipse-version"\:"[4.5.0,4.6.0)","java-version"\:"1.7","title"\:"Webclipse\: Limited support on Java 7","message"\:"Hey, we noticed that your Eclipse is running on Java 7\! While some of our tooling runs on Java 7, most of it will only work with Java 8 or later versions. To continue to benefit from the best of Webclipse, please consider using Java 8 to run Eclipse. We would also recommend using a more recent version of Eclipse for a better user experience.","action"\:{"label"\:"Upgrade Eclipse","url"\:"https\:\\/\\/www.eclipse.org\\/downloads\\/eclipse-packages\\/"}}]}
manifest.webclipse.download.etag="5bd0b0ab-fb5"
manifest.webclipse.download.modified.date=Wed, 24 Oct 2018 17\:49\:31 GMT
manifest.webclipse.download.url=http\://www.genuitec.com/updates/webclipse/ci/webclipse.json
release-notes-ids=2017ci12,2017ci14,ci20181024,ci20190313
webclipse.installed-release=1.11.0.201903292252
```

Can anybody let me know how to revert changes without opening the eclispe (as its throwing error) or any fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're sorry you ran into this rather disruptive problem - this issue affects Eclipse Neon users who have the DevStyle Icon Designer installed.

You need to delete the `com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.icon.designer_1.11.0.201906121516` plugin - please see [this post](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/unable-to-launch-eclipse-neon-nosuchfielderror-url/) for further details and specific instructions on the fix. Again, sincere apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have checked the post you shared, but there is no `com.genuitec.*.jar` or `com.genuitec.*` folder in the `[eclipse_root_folder]/plugins` folder.

Comment: The `com.genuitec.*` plugins found at `MY_HOME_DIRECTORY/.p2/pool/plugins`.